# Hide master pages when using design view in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

Is there a way to hide master pages when designing a child ASPX page using the Design view in Visual Studio 2010? My master pages handle some navigation controls and a login that totally freaks out when rendered in the Design view.

Comment: +1 for the login that freaks out

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really?

What should it do if your master page has 2 sections?

What you can do is put custom logic in your master page to check and see if it's design time, and do something different, like hide your navigation controls and login. This will cause it to be unable to be edited, even when editing the master page though.